# Why won't req.session set with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, express

I can't seem to get set anything for

```
req.session
```

I'm trying to store oauth token and the secret into a session so i can check them after the authorize callback. Here is my code

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express(),
    server  = require('http').createServer(app),
    io      = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    oauth   = require('oauth'),
    tumblr  = require('tumblr.js'),
    client  = {
        consumer_key: '1n9fMPxCBFBbcIGRImYKSK5wwDL6yux64S4DxEwiwzHTNuaIoD',
        consumer_secret: 'bW9YKbnwgxexyVx1AaxQr1QoemEkjd29p5U1WpbZ8r1XEH41C0'
    },
    consumer = new oauth.OAuth(
        "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token", "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token",
        client.consumer_key, client.consumer_secret, "1.0A", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/sessions/callback", "HMAC-SHA1");

server.listen(1337);

app.configure('dev', function(){
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: "topsecret" }));
});


app.get('/home', function(req, res){
    consumer.getOAuthRequestToken(function(err, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, results){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            //req.session.oauth.token = oauth_token;
            console.log('oauth.token: ' + oauth_token);
            //req.session.oauth.token_secret = oauth_token_secret;
            console.log('oauth.token_secret: ' + oauth_token_secret);
            res.redirect('http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token='+oauth_token);
        }
    });
});

app.get('/oauth/testapp', function(req, res){
    res.send('callback');
});
```

When I uncomment

```
req.session.oauth.token = oauth_token;
```

I get an error "cannot read property 'oauth' of undefined" also req.session displays undefined in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set the property `token` on an object `oauth` on the session. If the `oauth` object is not initialized, it will be `undefined`, and you can't set the `token` attribute. You first need to initialize the `oauth` object in the session. You could for instance do

```
req.session.oauth = {token: theToken}
```

This will create an object in the session and also set the `token` property of that object.

@robertklep figured out the other half of the solution: Make sure you're running with the correct environment. Since you have used `dev` in `app.configure`, you have to run node with `NODE_ENV=dev` for the configuration to be applied.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work I can't set anything within req.session at all. Even logging req I don't see a session parameter. console.log(req.session) shows undefined.

Comment: A quick test with a new express app works just fine with sessions, so it must be something with the session configuration then. Try with a fresh express app and see if there are any differences: `express --sessions testsessions`

Comment: @josh sounds like you're not running your app in the `dev` environment (`NODE_ENV=dev node app.js`, although it's usually called `development`). The middleware only applies for that environment, since you're using `app.configure('dev', ...)`.

Comment: Good point. I was just assuming it was run under the correct environment. Definitively check if the environment is set correctly.

Comment: @robertklep I was thinking it was something to do with the environment as well and that's what it was! I can now set the session thanks a lot add it as an answer and I'll accept, Thanks a ton!

Comment: @josh I wouldn't mind if Nils augmented his answer to include the part of the environment so you can accept his answer, because he's right as well :)

Comment: Thanks, @robertklep. I have updated the answer. Thanks for the joint effort. The points should have been split.

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = express();
app.configure('dev', function() {
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: "topsecret" }));
    app.use(app.router); // You need to add the router after the express.session
});
```

hope this can help you